# Struts 2 Multiple Keys in Multiple Resource Bundles [ How-To ]

Tags: struts2, struts

I am using

struts.custom.i18n.resources=file1,file2

### file1

enter.user   =  User name

### file2

enter.user   =  User name1

What will be the output for enter.user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the order you write the resources in struts.custom.i18n.resources property.

The last one 'wins'.

Now you have

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=file1,file2
```

file2 is the last so file2 wins and the output will be 'User name1'

if you had

```
struts.custom.i18n.resources=file2,file1
```

file1 would be the last so the output would be 'User name'